# Combo box and tab page : how to appear using IF-Esle

Tags: vb.net, combobox, tabs, tabpage

I'm making a messaging application wherein I am going to use a comboBox then when user choose a name, the corresponding tabpage will show.

here is my code; Please help me I dont know what is wrong here, I put the codes in combobox with SelectedIndexChanged event and its not working.
The problem is when I select Amavel, tabpage2 doesnt show :(

```
    If UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Criziel" Then
        TabPage1.Show()
    ElseIf UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Amavel" Then
        TabPage2.Show()
    ElseIf UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Edward" Then
        TabPage3.Show()
    End If
```

Comment: You forgot to describe a problem.  We are not mind readers

Comment: Why not just assign the `SelectedIndex` of the `ComboBox` to the `SelectedIndex` of the `TabControl`?

Answer (score 0):

**It should be like this:** 
    [name of tabcontrol].SelectedTab = [name of the tab]

```
If UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Criziel" Then
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage1
ElseIf UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Amavel" Then
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage2
ElseIf UserNameComboBox.SelectedItem = "Edward" Then
    TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabPage3
End If
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. Its now working. Thanks a lot. God Bless you.

Comment: Great! Don't forget to mark this answer if it's help you ;) happy coding!!